# Invert colors in whole PDF (conversion)

Tags: colors, pdf, conversion

How to create pdf with inverted colours of original one?

(Just like inverting whole screen with `xcalib -i -a`)

Preferably : not loosing hyperlinks. But it's not requirement. It would be nice if images also get inverted.

Comment: Maybe ImageMagick is a starting point -- I've just tried `convert orig.pdf -negate negative.pdf` but the result is not that good....maybe there're caveats I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 7):

A while ago, I was able to find a way to invert postscript files (although it failed for some files, I guess the ones which somehow override the change).

Adding `{1 exch sub} settransfer` as the first command in the file would invert the colors of the document (bitmap pictures included).

For the PDF → postscript conversion, you can use `pdftops` from `libpoppler` (AFAIK, the ghostscript `pdf2ps` generates suboptimal results). Unfortunately, this will not be kept when generating a PDF from the now negated postscript file.

Note that some pdf viewers have the ability to invert colors, such as `xpdf` (which does *not* invert bitmaps) and `evince` (which inverts everything, apparently no matter the format (PDF, postscript, djvu, ...)

Comment: Invert color in **evince**, `View -> Inverted Colors` OR `Ctrl-i` if you prefer keyboard shortcut.

Comment: For `xpdf`, use `xpdf -rv <filename>` to open the document in reverse video mode. Some more info from the man page: "This reverses the colors of everything except images. It may not always produce great results for PDF files which do weird things with color. This also causes the paper color to default to black."

Answer (score 0):

I rigged together a Ruby script (using Inkscape and ImageMagick as subroutines) [pdfinvert](https://github.com/akerbos/scripts/blob/master/pdfinvert.rb). It proceeds as follows:

1. Split PDF into individual pages.
2. Convert each page to SVG.
3. Invert colors¹ in the SVG; embedded PNG images are taken care of².
4. Reconvert each page to PNG.
5. Join pages together for the final result.

It was designed for drawings but it may work in many more cases (it seems to need some extensions to work with uncolored backgrounds).

---

1. You can also specify a color replacement table.
2. The approach probably extends to JPG or any other format ImageMagick's `convert` can deal with.